# WKWebView or UIWebView in iOS App, does this webview support WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

I would like to embed a browser in the iOS App, such as UIWebView or WKWebView, this browser can support webRTC?

Answer (score 3):

First you should prefer `WKWebView` over `UIWebView` if there is no special reason not to do it.

But no, neither of these two classes do support WebRTC, only the Safari iOS browser does. Not even `SFSafariViewController` does support it.

If you like you can file a bug report (aka Radar) here and hope for iOS 12: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Thanks.There is a way, use native.

Comment: @tianglin what do you mean by use native?

Comment: filed bug report hoping for iOS 13